# Perl - Padding a string with whitespace and printing it

Tags: string, perl, concatenation, whitespace

I have a string "A" and a string "B".

I want to add a certain amount of whitespace between A and B, then print it. I want the resulting print to be "A (lots of spaces here) B".

My idea is to pad "A" with whitespace to the right.
I tried to accomplish this by:

```
$A .= (" " x 10)
```

then concatenate A and B, and print it.

However, this resulting print is "A \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ B"

How do I get whitespace instead of these backslashes in my print? I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: The code you posted does not add any backslashes.

Comment: The code for concatenation and printing is missing, I assume that is where you used quotemeta. You should never post partial code, always include a code sample that, when executed, does exactly what you say it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted does not produce the output you describe.

```
$ perl -Mv5.14 -e'
   my $A = "A";
   my $B = "B";
   $A .= " " x 10;
   say $A . $B;
'
A          B
```

If you know the amount of space you need, generating it using `" " x 10` is quite appropriate.

```
$ perl -Mv5.14 -e'say "A", " " x 10, "B";'
A          B
```

If instead, you know the size of the column, you could use `printf`.

```
$ perl -Mv5.14 -e'say sprintf "%-10s %s", "A", "B";'
A          B
```

And there's also [forms](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form).

```
$ perl -Mv5.14 -e'
  use Perl6::Form qw( form );
  print form "{<<<<<<<<} {<<<<<<<<}", "A", "B";
'
A          B
```

Comment: You're correct. It must be something specific to my code. Do you know what could cause these backslashes? @ikegami @

Comment: `quotemeta`? (There would be a slash before the first space, though.)

Comment: Yes I saw something about quotemeta in my logs. How would you go about removing that?

Comment: If you don't want to use it, don't

Comment: `"...\Q...\E..."` is 100% equivalent to `"..." . quotemeta("...") . "..."`